# main activity implementing a listener interface for updating UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, listener, handler

**So first of all I figured out how to update the UI from another thread. I'm using AsyncTask and the Handler class for anything else**

**But** in the first place I did it wrong and now I really want to find out what was wrong.

So my first try was to create an java interface `MyListener` with a methode `updateUI()` and let the main activity implement that listener interface. Than I registered the main activity as listener in a thread that handles http requests. From that thread I called `MyListener.updateUI()` after the request was done. `updateUI()` updates some textviews with the request's result.

This doesn't work in android. And I did not expect that. And I don't know why.
The exception told me that I have to make these updates from the UI thread.

I don't understand why `updateUI()` doesn't run in the UI-thread when I call `MyListener.updateUI()` with the main activity implementing `updateUI()` from the listener interface.

Could you explain me this behavior?

Comment: post your code and others could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting this error because the control was still inside the Background thread... though you have called the interface method which has been implemented in you activity.So in order to get the control back to your UI thread you need to post using a handler.The control  does not goes from the Background thread to the UI thread by just calling the method which is located in your activity.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: So when a background thread is calling a method that is implemented by a class running in the main thread, the method runs still in the background thread?
(Oh man, I'm developer for many years now and yet I didn't seem to fully understand how the thread control works.)

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have excuted the http request in other thread, but you do not use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), right? I suggest that you should use that class, excute http request in `doInBackground` method (because it works off main thread), and call `MyListener.updateUI()` on `onPostExcute` because this method is always get called in main thread. Have a try and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter if you are calling `MyListener.updateUI()` in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method or any other if you are doing that from another Thread it will throw you an exception, because you can update View's only in the applications Main Thread. To achieve this you can do something like that :

```
public static void updateUI(){

       ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // update your UI here and be sure to give the activity context, not getApplicationContext();
        }
    });

}
```

put this in your Activity and in your `onCreate()` do something like that :

```
public static Context mContext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   mContext = this;
}
```

and call `updateUI()` from whatever thread you want to do it.

Of course this isn't the only way you can update your interface.You can take a look at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) implementation in Android SDK. It's a really powerful class and I think it will do the thing which you want more efficiently.